# issue on withcolumnRename .I want to rename the column not possible todo in databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I am trying to rename my **first name** column into **name**. withcolumnRename it is not working. Is there any way to resolve this issue and also i created temp table but still i got same error

`df1= spark.read.option("header",True).csv("/filestore/emp.csv") df1.printSchema()`

**This is my Schema**:
[link 1](https://i.imgur.com/K89R91Q.png)

**`withcolumnRename`** it is not working .

[link 2](https://i.imgur.com/2pziTaF.png)

and also i tried below approach also still no use . is there any way to resolve this problem.

[link 3](https://i.imgur.com/cNqFd9t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space in your 2nd, 3rd and 4th column names.

Try the below line -

```
df_renamed = df1.withColumnRenamed(" first name", "name").show()
```

Comment: But in your link 2, there is no space before "f"

Comment: hi mpr, thankyou for the answer . now it's working fine i tried your approach. issue on  space.

Comment: yes you are right JayashankarGS, using index also  working fine. thank you